# Java Hashmap from csv

Tags: java, hashmap, lookup

I'm trying to use HAshmap in a class in order to, from other classes, look up product descriptions given the product code.
Whith the setter (populate) everything seems to work fine , but when I'm tryig to use a getter (getdesc) i get an error.

The csv file i'm using has only 2 filds (cod,des). Later, I plan to populate the hashmap from JDBC SQL server source.

I'm probabbly using the wrong syntax. I'll apreciate if anyone can help.

That's my current class code:

```
package bookRecommender;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;



public class ProdutoDescricao


{

        public static void main(String[] args) {}

    @SuppressWarnings({ "resource", "unused" })
    public static void populate(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Map<String, ArrayList<String>> produtos=null;
        try { 

               String csvFile = "Data/produto_descricao.csv";


               BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile));
               String line = "";
               StringTokenizer st = null;

               produtos= new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();

               int lineNumber = 0; 
               int tokenNumber = 0;

                           while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
               lineNumber++;



                st = new StringTokenizer(line, ",");
                            while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                tokenNumber++;


                            String token_lhs=st.nextToken();
                            String token_rhs= st.nextToken();


                            ArrayList<String> arrVal = produtos.get(token_lhs);
                            if (arrVal == null) {
                                arrVal = new ArrayList<String>();
                                produtos.put(token_lhs,arrVal);
                            }
                            arrVal.add(token_rhs);                            

                            }
                        }

                        System.out.println("Final Hashmap is : "+produtos);




} catch (Exception e) {
               System.err.println("CSV file cannot be read : " + e);
             }

    }

  public  String getdesc (long cod)  
  {

    return produto.get(cod);
//Here is the sysntax error
  }

}
```

Comment: You say there's an error - but you haven't told us what the error *is*. It would also be better if you could produce a *short* but complete program demonstrating the problem. I'm sure you don't need this much code to demonstrate what's wrong.

Comment: (Note that you've never declared a `produto` variable, and your `produtos` variable is a local variable within `main`...)

Comment: It is preferable that you do not input your whole executing code, but rather a [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org). Please consider updating your code to help others to help you.

Comment: Additionally, instead of suppressing warnings, fix the things they're warning about.

Comment: The error is "produto cannot be resolved ". Definitely there is a syntax error or the class is not well structured. Any hint?

Answer (score 0):

`produtos= new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>()`  `produtos` it has no values it is blank.

`ArrayList<String> arrVal = produtos.get(token_lhs);` this line has issue, you have to first add values in your map then get those values.

Comment: It seems that in the getdesc method the hashmap is empty. I'm Sorry but I'm a newbie in java,  and my question is probably  dumb.How can I change my code so it can work with setter and getter and be available to other classes?

Answer (score 0):

You have a map with String key and ArrayList values types, but you trying to retrieve value with long key and String values type.

```
 public  ArrayList<String> getdesc (String cod)  
  {
    return produtos.get(cod);
  }
```

Also declare field 'produtos':

```
 private static Map<String, ArrayList<String>> produtos;
```

Full class code: http://pastebin.com/QLZryqT8

Comment: I changed my method to  match your suggestion, but got the same error : "product cannot be resolved".

Comment: The link seems to be broken.

Comment: The link is ok. My firewall blocked the page.

Comment: I changed the code as you suggested and it compiles. When i try to use this methos in another class i got an exception.Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at bookRecommender.ProdutoDescricao.getdesc(ProdutoDescricao.java:84)
 at bookRecommender.teste.main(teste.java:70)

Comment: piece of code used in the second class:     ProdutoDescricao produtos = new ProdutoDescricao(); 
 ProdutoDescricao.populate(null);
 System.out.println(produtos.getdesc("60597"));

Comment: @Nelson make sure that file path is correct and reading is executed, also in what line of code do you get the NPE?

Comment: The file is correct because the populate works perfectly.I'm getting the exception in the last statement:System.out.println(produtos.getdesc("60597"))

Comment: @Nelson print out the content of produtos map before getting values from it

Comment: I suppose you're refering to aplly printl the entore object. If So, I've tried this before and got the same exception.  produtos.populate(null);
  System.out.println(produtos);
  System.out.println(produtos.getdesc("60597"));

Comment: Output of  System.out.println(produtos) is : bookRecommender.ProdutoDescricao@181c5f3

Comment: for (Map.Entry entry : produtos.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(entry.getValue() "" : "+ entry.getKey());

Comment: Sorry, I didn't got it (I'm  newbie in the java world). What am I supposed to do with this piece of code ?

Comment: @Nelson print out all entries from map